Tabulator loads all rows even with progressiveLoad set to scroll
I'm having a problem with progressiveLoad: 'scroll'.  When the table loads, I can see it requesting all the data (page 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8).  Then when I scroll in the table it calls the endpoints again.
With the the height of the table and the size of the rows, I can only see 3 rows when the table loads (expected). I don't think all of the loads are supposed to happen when it loads the table initially when set to scroll.  It's like like it's doing load and scroll mode at the same time.
In the screenshot you can see it loaded all 8 pages (not supposed to do this), then when I started to scroll it started at page 3 (this is what is supposed to happen).

Below is my config
  headerSortClickElement: 'icon',
  movableColumns: true,
  persistence: {
      sort: true,
      columns: true
  },
  height: '200px',
  ajaxURL: getBaseUrl(),
  ajaxURLGenerator: (url, _, params) => {
      return (
          url + endpointUrl + '?' + new URLSearchParams(params).toString()
      );
  },
  ajaxConfig: {
      headers: {
          Authorization: getAuthorizationHeader()
      }
  },
  progressiveLoad: 'scroll',
  progressiveLoadScrollMargin: 300,
  paginationSize: 2


After some troubleshooting, it's because of something with the way we have the table nested in React.  I moved the table to the top level component and it works as expected.
